# Getting the C++ compilers in Code::Blocks and Visual Studio to adhere to C++(11) standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, codeblocks

I use two C++ compilers / IDEs. (1) g++ in Code::Blocks and (2) Visual C++ in Visual Studio.

I have some question on how to set up the compiler in the way I want it to be.

Code::Blocks: I want to make G++ follow standard C++. For example:

```
int x; 
cin >> x; 
int arr[x];
```

...wouldn't work in standard C++.

In standard C++, one has to use dynamic allocation. For example, the Visual C++ compiler would reject this code. However, this code would work in Code::Blocks.

How do I make g++ reject this code?

Also, how do I tell g++ and Visual C++ 2013 to follow and only follow C++11 standard? It seems to me the default one is still C++98/03.

Comment: Codeblocks and Visual Studio aren't compilers, they're IDEs.  Codeblocks will use whatever compiler you tell it to and Visual Studio uses it's own proprietary compiler.  For gcc, consider using the `-ansi` flag.

Comment: The compiler shipped with MSVC is called MSC, but you can plug in other compilers, too. Further, that compiler is also shipped with some SDKs. Concerning Codeblocks, it is often used with GCC as compiler. So, your question is basically how to tell each compiler to conform to a certain standard, which is almost too easy to find out using a tiny bit of research.

Comment: `-pedantic` flag works for both `gcc` and `clang` and tell them to warn about code that is not standard, there must be a way to set this flag. You can use `-pedantic-errors` to make it an error.

Comment: Fun fact, disabling Microsoft specific extensions to C++ in MSVC is no longer supported and also means you can't build WIN32 apps as the SDK headers are not clean

Comment: @paulm that's *awesome*.

Comment: @Mr.Llama *gcc* `-ansi` flag is not the right one, do not use it! Check the docs to see what it does...

Comment: There are three parts to this question, namely (1) what options to use for the compilers, (2) how those options can be configured or preconfigured for command line use, and (3) how they can be configured or preconfigured in each IDE.

Answer (score 1):

### Compiler options for standard-conformance.

With g++ you want, at minimum,

- `-std=c++11` for the C++11 standard.
- `-pedantic` to warn about use of language extensions.
- `-Wall -Wextra` to up the warning level to reasonable.

With Visual C++ you want, at minimum,

- `/nologo` to turn off a verbose version and copyright message,
- `/EHsc` to turn on exception support,
- `/GR` to turn on RTTI support, *Run Time Type Information* such as `dynamic_cast`,
- `/W4` to up the warning level to reasonable.

With Visual C++ there is no special option to indicate the C++ standard version.

### How to preset options for command line use.

MinGW g++ generally (one exception is the Nuwen distribution) defaults to producing executables that rely on DLLs that reside in the mingw\bin directory, which means that you generally need that in your `PATH` environment variable.

This means that it's not such a good idea to add options via a batch file or shortcut or command intepreter macro. Instead use option **`-dumpspecs`** and redirection to create a **specs** file (with that name) in the directory specified by this Windows command:

```
g++ --print-search-dirs | find "install:"
```

Read up on how to edit that file, then fix it. ;-)

You might want to set the `CPATH` environment variable to your general include directory.

With Visual C++:

- Compilers options can be preset in the `CL` environment variable.
- Include paths in the `INCLUDE` variable.
- Library paths in the `LIB` variable.
- Linker options can be preset in the `LINK` variable.

For the linker options you may want to have `/entry:mainCRTStartup` to support ordinary standard `main` startup function also when producing a GUI subsystem executable. However this conflicts a little with MFC. It's been *many* years since I did anything MFC so if you want details or solution please post a separate question which others can answer.

### How to set options in each IDE (Code::Blocks, Visual Studio).

This is as simple as reading each IDE's documentation. ;-)

Note that options can be set both globally and per project.

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra` please. `-Wall` is pathetic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: thanks. but does the `-Wextra` warning about uninitialized work generally without `-O`? i didn't want to say anything that i don't *know*. i remember in old days it needed `-O`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: i looked at (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-W-284). it says `-Wextra` enables, among other things, `-Wuninitialized`. some/many years ago, one had to then specify at least *some* optimization in order to engage the analyzis than enabled it to warn about use of uninitialized variables in general, although it could do it in special cases. i just wonder if you know how it is now? because if i amend the answer with `-Wextra`, if it practically also requires `-O` then that should IMHO be mentioned, and otherwise not.

Comment: I've never heard of that, never tested for it, and never had a problem. The documentation explains that `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` is possible only in the presence of optimisations; `-Wuninitialized` will work only for variables that are not elided by data flow analysis. Either way I don't see what bearing this has on including `-Wextra` in your answer.

Comment: Well it seems to me "-Wall -Wextra" will give you some error, but it doesn't prevent from compiling...

Comment: @user4099855: It works nicely with MinGW g++ 4.9.1 and 4.8.2. Option `-Wextra` was introduced somewhere after version 3.2.3, so if your compiler doesn't like it it may just be a too old version. Note that if it gives an error (i.e. your compiler is too old), then it does prevent you from compiling, in the sense that no executable is produced.